# Load next js based on client side data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to build a next.js app that would work like this:

1. Initially serve a splash screen and retrieve the screen size of the client
2. Send the screen size data to the server which responds with a react app that gets injected into the client browser

Is it possible to do this through next.js? If so, then can I also dynamically get a new react app if the screen is resized?

Comment: server side react app is an oxymoron

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but I'm guessing that the *actual* problem would be much easier to solve if you told why you'd want to do that.

Comment: There is no reason I can think of to do this.  The whole point of nextjs is to serve html for seo purposes.  You can manipulate your react app on screen size once it's already sent to the browser.  If you send a splash screen first then thats what search engines will index and you are losing any benefit of using nextjs and you may as well just use react without it.

Comment: @SteveK Ok, is it possible to serve two different apps depending on the user agent (device)?

Comment: @GuyIncognito because I have two entirely different websites for mobile and desktop devices

Comment: If you truly have different websites with completely different content and such different layouts that they can't be dynamically adapted with CSS, the traditional and vastly simpler method is to have a different subdomain or directory for the mobile site and redirect the mobile users there (as in e.g. `en.m.wikipedia.org`).

Comment: @GuyIncognito that's a good idea, thank you!